# How to find the jmp address during a x86 function call?

Tags: assembly, x86

Suppose we have a call foo statement. So when the assembler encounters a call statement it breaks it down into -

```
push ip + 6
jmp <addr of foo>
```

I have the return address in a register ebx. Now I want to find out the "addr of foo". How do I do it? I want to confirm that the push statement is present before the jmp. Will the memory map look something like this?

```
-------
push (what will be the value stored in this byte?? opcode ??)
-------
jmp (what will be the value stored in this byte?? opcode ??)
-------
jmp byte 1
-------
jmp byte 2
-------
jmp byte 3
-------
jmp byte 4
-------
return address stored in ebx
-------
```

What are the opcodes for push and jmp?

Comment: `call` is an instruction that is executed by the processor. The assembler doesn't transform it. You can think of it as being equivalent to a `push` and a `jmp`, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: @wj32: ok if call is executed by processor. How do I get the address of the place where it jumps to?

Comment: @wj32: What is the memory map of call statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assembler does not break down `call` into two instructions. `call` is a separate instruction that has its own machine-language opcodes.

There are different opcodes for `call`, depending on the type of call (near or far, address given as relative value or indirectly in memory contents, etc.) For the normal type of call in 32-bit mode (relative near call), you would have the opcode `E8` followed by a 4-byte value that specifies the target address, relative to the next instruction after the `call`.

For more information, see the entry for `call` in the [Intel Manual](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), volume 2.

Comment: Can you please point me to the reference where you got the opcode for call.

Comment: @Bruce: I added a link to the standard reference.

Answer (score 2):

As @wj32 says in the comment above, `CALL` is a single instruction - it doesn't get "broken down" into a `PUSH` and a `JMP`. The opcode for `CALL` can be `E8`, `9A` or `FF` depending on how the destination address is specified. See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M](http://ttp://www.intel.com/assets/pdf/manual/253666.pdf) in section 3.2, under "CALL", for full details of the various different opcodes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `call`. You can get all the information you need from the [Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/). This includes instruction encoding, etc. I'll quote the relevant bit below (for near calls):

> The target operand specifies either an absolute offset in the code segment (an offset
>   from the base of the code segment) or a relative offset (a signed displacement relative
>   to the current value of the instruction pointer in the EIP register; this value
>   points to the instruction following the CALL instruction). The CS register is not
>   changed on near calls.

Answer (score 0):

use a dissembler and i think u might end up with the absolute address of foo! cause the linker does that and the compiled code doesnt has the names. same for global variables
eg if u assemble u get j foo
but compile then dissamble nd ull get j 0X45335